# Choose between single or double buttons for two actions

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, user-expectation, user-research, experience

I'm trying to find what is the best approach for the following scenario.

I'm building Music Player App(iOS). For each played song we have two options :

1. Add the song to My Music Library
2. Add the song to a new/exist Playlist

I'm trying to super-minimize the UI - so i've tried the one button concept.

When clicking the plus button, it's automated adding the song into my **Music Library**, and a bottom card menu pops with the options to add to a new/exists playlist(and cancel).

[image]

That said, here is the issue:

After the user click the plus button and adds the song, he can remove it by clicking the plus again(which will be a X button). But with this scenario, if i'll not be adding the song into one of the playlist, i'll not be able to open the playlist menu again, unless he will remove - add it again.

Is it "okay" to allow the playlist options only when adding the song? Or it's a must to add a playlist button for future use(just in case)? All tho' adding and removing the song will pop it up again + you'll be able to add the song from the playlist it self and not thru the song.

What's your thoughts about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the "Add/+" button, you can have /(downarrow) selector which could either accordian-open a drop-down menu or pop-open a modal box which would allow setting indivual on-the-fly user-action preferences.  (Add/Delete 
Behavior Settings)

Similar to how myfonts.com handles the behavior selections for viewing overview samples.:

[image]

The Behavior Settings Area could also be used for related actions such as "reset to default" button,  Also, great place allow access to the "playlist menu" which you mentioned.

You may consider implementing a "Remove/-".  Grayed out until a selected song has already been added:

[image]

There is still enough room to implement a couple of more buttons, such as a heart for tagging it as a favorites without adding it to any specific playlist  (non-selected start out as white, with green indicating it is already tagged as a fav and red being that it has been tagged as not a fav).  Additionally, you could have a thumb-up, thumb-down to tag item as liked/disliked without actually adding to playlist.

In addition to "playlists", you could implement "virtual albums", which  could then be included in playlists.  Obviously, being able to clone an album or playlist would also be a good feature.

--
Best of Luck with this probject!

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for answering!  I'm trying to minimize the feature at the app, really trying to focus only on playlists and general music library(made a research). I liked the dropdown list option, do i'm still looking for a way to solve in only with a single button. You think it's solvable? I'm trying to minimize the UI as much as possible. Adding another button, IMO is not necessary the best option, due the psychologic effect on the app usage(made a research as well)

Comment: Perhaps allowing the user to choose the layout of the lower area would be a way to go.Finger sizes and dexterity differs greatly, so I do see where having the entire bottom area dedicated to this

Comment: Finger sizes and dexterity differs greatly, so I do see where having the entire bottom area dedicated to this makes sense.  Perhaps two settings (minimal/expanded) which could be toggled which would allow a user to choose which screen view they want to use.  Would not necessarily need the visible \/ button, just something like pressing continuously for several seconds would bring up the settings menu.  Empty space does not always need to be filled.

Comment: Also, appreciate the fact that you are keeping the "creeping features" of tons of extra bells and whistles down is good.  I like the term "view," but you could also use "layout."

Comment: Showing my age here:  WordStar pioneered the concept of short-cuts (cutnpaste ctl-c ctl-v)    Expert Mode -- Minimalist layout (No Extra Buttons/No annoying hints).  Learning/Newbie Mode -- Extra Buttons/ Functions showing, also pop-up hints.    Supporting both groups = wider user base.  Kudos to you actually researching.

Comment: Very cool.Actually i never was a fun for different functions group for each "user understanding level" (+~). I believe that you can almost always achieve cross design which will be convenient for aged users and new ones. The main question is here - We can solve our scenario very easily by adding a simple button. Let's take Spotify for example. They added two buttons,one at each side. Exactly for my two options. Will they go along side by side, instead of the (+)? Adding a Spotify screenshot : http://prntscr.com/btbvp2 .I'm just thinking that add another button for simple/similar task is stupid

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a little strange to have that button there with all that space wasted in the most important area of the screen (close to the fingers);
2. Having only one button will always make the user go for 2 clicks (3 clicks with the selection of a playlist) for any action and in time one of the 2 actions will get the most usage (track that) and will become frustrating;
3. Having separate buttons will be in my opinion the best way to go but you need to have extremely "expressive" buttons so that the user learns fast or remembers quickly; also you need to have probably a fast "undo" action if the Add to My Music Library will be instant.

Comment: Hey Ciprian, Thank you for answering! A few thoughts regarding your answer. I thought that making this "white spaces" around the (+) button, will mark him even more from the rest of the buttons. My goal is to make the user add songs as much as he can, so he'll grow his library. That's why i've focused so much on the plus button. More over, adding another button, may hurt the UI, and take the "focus". Apple music and spotify, both made separate buttons for Music library and playlists. Do you think it's solvable in a single button, some how? (even in the expense of extra clicks)

Comment: By making a button "more visible" you won't make users use it more because it's a matter of choice, desire and need, people won't add a song to a playlist if they don't like it or it is based on personal preference. Apple music is a bad example because currently everybody is complaining about the usability of the app so try to stay away from it and analyse other tools like Spotify. I still believe that having a direct action without more clicks is the way to go, because this is a basic/repetitive action. Try maybe placing the buttons over the song cover/img. A button won't hurt your UI.

Comment: The main question is here - We can solve our scenario very easily by adding a simple button. Let's take Spotify for example. They added two buttons,one at each side. Exactly for my two options. Will they go along side by side, instead of the (+)? Adding a Spotify screenshot : http://prntscr.com/btbvp2 . I might be overthinking it, But again, add a song to music library and add a song to a playlist, both so familiar, drives me nuts i need to separate them. I mean. it may be the standard, but i think it shouldn't - I'm sure there is a better solution

Comment: I give you the ultimate answer to your problem and I am not kidding: get 3-5 friends, couple of treats, make 2 simple prototypes in Invision or anything else and test them. You will have your answer in no time :)

Comment: Will make it - come back to you with an update :)